# How can I use the try-with-resources patter in reactor, if resource is a Mono?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a client, which is being created as a Mono, e.g.

`Mono<MyClient> myClientMono = ...`

The `MyClient` class implements `Closeable` interface, so you can use the standard java try-with-resources pattern.

What's the best way to use resource wrapped in a `Mono`?

I understand how to use Mono.using() to mimic try-with-resources if the resource is a regular object, like a `InputStream`.

However, how can I make sure myclient is being closed after it has been used with Reactor?

I could do this:

```
Mono.using(() -> myClientMono.block(),
        myClient -> myClient.doSomething(),
        myClient.close())
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

however, this will be blocking and cannot be used in an asynchronous thread.

I could do something like this and close the client after it has been used:

```
myClientMono
  .flatMap( myClient -> { 
        var a = myClient.doSomething();
        myClient.close();
        return Mono.just(a);
     })
  .subscribe(Sytem.out::println);
```

This - however - does not close the client if an error occurs.

I wonder if there's a better solution?

Comment: Do you mean [`Mono.doFinally`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doFinally-java.util.function.Consumer-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to use [Mono.usingWhen](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#usingWhen-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) or [Flux.usingWhen](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#usingWhen-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-).

In both case, you provide a resource publisher, that will be called each time the user subscribe, to produce a fresh resource.

Let's see that in an example:

```java
import java.time.Duration;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class UsingWhen {

    /** Simulates a closeable resource. Prints a message when opening and closing. */
    public static class ReactiveResourceMock implements AutoCloseable {

        public ReactiveResourceMock() { System.out.println("OPENING"); }

        Flux<Integer> content() { return Flux.range(1, 3); }

        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception { System.out.println("CLOSING"); };
    }

    /** Simulates async value opening */
    public static Mono<ReactiveResourceMock> open() {
        return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(200))
                   .map(i -> new ReactiveResourceMock());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono<ReactiveResourceMock> openResource = open();

        Flux<Integer> flow = Flux.usingWhen(
                openResource,
                ReactiveResourceMock::content,
                resource -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                    resource.close();
                    return 1;
                }))
                .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("CANCELLED"))
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("COMPLETED"));

        System.out.println("VERIFY FLOW CONTROL:");
        flow.doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockLast();

        System.out.println("WHAT HAPPENS IN CASE OF ERROR:");
        flow.limitRate(1)
            .map(i -> i / (i % 2))
            .onErrorReturn(-1)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockLast();
    }
}
```

The program above prints:

```
VERIFY FLOW CONTROL:
OPENING
1
2
3
CLOSING
COMPLETED
WHAT HAPPENS IN CASE OF ERROR:
OPENING
1
CANCELLED
-1
CLOSING
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Works beautifully for my use case.  Thanks so much.